When should I notify employer that I bought a house?
I am closing on my house in about 30 days. I have not notified my employer that my partner and I bought a house. I work in a small office & I am debating on when I should tell my employer. The house I bought is 45-50 minutes away from my job, so I either have to get a new job after closing or see if they will allow me to WFH a few days a week. How do I discuss this with my employer to make it seem like I’m not quitting, but ask if they will work with me?

You didn't do this before looking for houses? It's a little late in the game to be trying to force their hand.

@JoelEtherton I did not. I went under contract almost 7 months ago since I am building the house. It’s not my intention to force their hand, but I am running out of options. I don’t particularly enjoy my job in the first place, but if I was able to WFH, it would be possible to manage until I find a job that’s closer to home.

Why would you need to notify them that you bought a house? a 45-50 minute commute? Join the club. Many, many people have a commute that is that long or longer.

I live 2 hours away from my job. Worked their for nearly 11 years now. Why would they care how far you live from work?

Frame Challenge
This is not a question about notifying them you have bought a house, this is a question about wanting to Work from Home.
First up - 45-50 minutes for a Commute into the office - that sounds great. I regularly used to commute over an hour into some of my old jobs. Depending on what your location is, this might be Average or a bit above Average - but the point that I am making is this:
This is not a significant enough factor that I would give it any additional consideration in assessing your request
Further-more - You presumably knew where you bought the house, you knew where your office was - and without a prior WFH agreement (if there is a company Policy, this might be different) - you made your choice. Your choices are not a reason for me to change policy.
Now.
That all said...
There is no reason why you cannot have the conversation with your boss about the possibility of Working from Home. My advice would be to do the commute for a few weeks and then ask:

Hey Boss, I recently bought a house, I thought I would be fine with the commute but it is a bit worse than I thought. What are my options at looking at a hybrid WFH arrangement. I know we have important meetings on X, Y and Z, so I was thinking that if I work from home not on those days, that would really help me out.



I am closing on my house in about 30 days.

Congratulations.

I have not notified my employer that my partner and I bought a house.

That is ok. They might not need to know. They may already know.

I work in a small office & I am debating on when I should tell my employer. The house I bought is 45-50 minutes away from my job,

Some of the reason you should tell them.

HR and payroll may need to know. The new home may be in a different jurisdiction that can impact taxes or insurance. Ask them what forms need to be submitted. The requirements are specific to the locations.
If the change in commute will impact your availability. The longer commute may mean that you have to change your working hours. In some offices that is trivial, but in other offices that require the office be staffed from 06:00 to 18:00, that is more complex. This should have been discussed with your management before committing to a new place to live because how you get to work should be part of the calculus when deciding on where to live.
In some positions the change in financial situation needs to be reported. Purchasing a house could be one of those things that needs to be reported.

Note that the first two items on the list have nothing to do with purchasing a house, they are related to moving. The impact isn't just to the amount of time spent commuting. It is also how that change impacts the hours you can be in the office. It also can make your arrival time more inconsistent.

so I either have to get a new job after closing or see if they will
allow me to WFH a few days a week.

If this is important enough to you, that should have been discussed before making the move. Of course if you asked before the decision to move, and they were firm in their denial, then when they are told that you moved anyway they might be worried that you are not going to be around for long.

How do I discuss this with my employer to make it seem like I’m not
quitting, but ask if they will work with me?

That is always the difficulty. You need to make sure that you don't give them an ultimatum. Giving them an impression that you are about to quit, before you have started looking for a job puts you on dangerous ground.
You should do the longer drive for a while. That will let you know how it impacts your situation, and how it can be addressed. You may have to do it long enough to know that you have seen the variety of commuting situations. I work in place down the road from a high school. The traffic patterns are far different in the summer than in the school year.
Basing your suggestions on actual data, instead of guessing on the impact, will give you the ability to make multiple suggestions: later start times, earlier start times, 10 hour days, working from home.
You will be asking them if there is any flexibility. their answer will depend on your exact job, and company policy. It will also depend on their management style.
As a person involved in hiring new employees, knowing the general location where they live is important. I don't want to reject somebody based on where they live. In fact I won't reject them for that reason. But I do make sure they are aware of the commuting distance. Sometimes they missed the line in the job advertisement giving the location. Sometimes they were hoping they could work in a closer office. Sometimes they understand the challenge, then quit 6 months later. But at least we discussed it.

It's probably not news to them. The mortgage company would have rang them for confirmation on your employment status and salary.

This must depend on country. When I bought my house, the mortgage company just needed three months of salary slips and a copy of my employment contract.

Sooner the better if you have a good relationship AND you want to keep it.
You haven't said if your job is realistically able to be WFH. We will assume that it is possible.
Letting them know in a non-threating way.
Consider waiting until a second conversation about asking for WFH. It is a little on the icky side, but letting the boss absorb the first part before asking for the second part might help. You know your boss better than we do. If they would take it as being as being less than truthful, then bring it up right away.
Either way, sooner the better.
